# Crystal Reports formula field IF LIKE

Tags: sql, filter, crystal-reports, formula

I'm a little confused with Crystal Reports [LIKE] pattern operator, compared to SQL's [IN] operator.

I have inherited maintenance of an old report that uses FORMULA FIELDS to qualify the data used in SELECTION FORMULAS > RECORD SELECTION.

One of the FORMULA FIELDS uses [LIKE] to limit the records returned.

**EXAMPLE IN CRYSTAL:**

```
IF {table.column} LIKE ["A","B","C"]
```

**COMPARED TO SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN ("A","B","C")
```

I can't find documentation that uses LIKE in this way. 
Since I can't find supporting documentation for LIKE I question if this is the "best practice" for filtering content. Is there a better way?

Thanks,

-Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the correct way to use in crystal.... it will pick the values that satisfies the like operator... also you mentioned it in record selection formula so it will be directly included in where clause of the query generated in crystal

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Use below link to know the documentation of the crystal reports.

[Link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic666.html)

I have pasted for `Like` operator but if you want to see documentation for formulas or  build different formulas you can use above link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a link to supporting documentation that shows this in use?

Comment: You can check my edit for the `Like` documentation and also `Crystal` documentation

Comment: You can type `Like` in search to get the documentation and similarly for any search criteria

Comment: Thanks for the link Siva. The IBM documentation [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/topic/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic901.html?resultof=%22%6c%69%6b%65%22%20) is the same as that Crystal Reports gives.

Comment: FROM THE IBM DOCUMENTATION SITE:
`Examples
{customer.FIRST NAME} like "D?n"


TRUE, where {customer.FIRST NAME} = Dan or Don.
{customer.FIRST NAME} like "D?n"

FALSE, where {customer.FIRST NAME} = Doug or Rob.
{customer.LAST NAME} like "*s?n*"

TRUE, where {customer.LAST NAME} = Johnson or Olson or Olsen.
{customer.LAST NAME} like "*s?n*"

FALSE, where {customer.LAST NAME} = Johnston or Smith.`

Comment: I'm not finding an example of: `IF {table.column} LIKE ["A","B","C"]`

Comment: Can't provide the exact example of what you are looking for.. but to the extent of knowledge I have you can use... If you are not totally in aggrement with the approach you can use `in` in place of `Like` in crystal reports.